# How to deploy to Vercel with dynamically generated package from Prisma

Tags: javascript, npm, next.js, prisma, vercel

I'm using Prisma and Vercel. Prisma dynamically generates the Prisma client, but Vercel caches the old client and doesn't rebuild it unless I log in to Vercel and click "redeploy" which forces it to reinstall all the packages.

Is there any way to force this one package to just rebuild every time I push to GitHub, so that Vercel won't use the cached version? I noticed that if I change the package version, it will rebuild, but that's a pretty big hack. Is there some way to flag it to rebuild every time?

```
"@prisma/client": "3.8.0" // some special flag to prevent this from getting cached?
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What command are you using to build the app?

Recommended approach is to use this one:

```
// package.json scripts section
"vercel-build": "prisma generate && prisma migrate deploy && next build",
```

It will generate new prisma client and definitions, apply migrations and then build the app for production.

[More info in the docs as always](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/deployment/deployment-guides/deploying-to-vercel#vercel-build-hook)

Answer (score 0):

```
"scripts" {
    "postinstall": "prisma generate"
  }

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}
```

https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/deployment/serverless/deploy-to-vercel

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35728372)