# Production build fails: Type error: Property 'companies' does not exist on type 'PrismaClient ...... whereas local build passes

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I am building a nextjs project on vercel with typescript and prisma.
Versions:
"next": "13.0.3"
"typescript": "4.9.3"
"prisma": "^4.6.1"

build is passing locally, but fails on vercel:

```
Type error: Property 'companies' does not exist on type 'PrismaClient<PrismaClientOptions, never, RejectOnNotFound \| RejectPerOperation \| undefined>'.
--
01:05:17.287 |  
01:05:17.287 | 71 \|     },
01:05:17.288 | 72 \|     companies: async () => {
01:05:17.288 | > 73 \|       const companies = await prisma.companies.findMany();
01:05:17.289 | \|                                      ^
01:05:17.289 | 74 \|       return companies;
01:05:17.289 | 75 \|     },
01:05:17.289 | 76 \|   },
```

whereas typescript detects 'companies' as property of prisma
tried to regenerate Prisma Client, deleting the model and consequently using: prisma format, prisma generate, prisma db push.
I am using mongodb

./prisma/schema.prisma

```
model companies {
  id   String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  v    Int?   @map("__v")
  name String
}
```

production builds were passing before adding this new model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to make sure that `npx prisma generate` is a part of your build process.
In your package.json you can define the generate command in the build process like this:

```json
{
  "name": "deployment-example-prisma-vercel",
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "4.7.1",
    "next": "13.0.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "vercel-build": "prisma generate && prisma migrate deploy && next build",
    "prisma:generate": "prisma generate"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prisma": "4.7.1"
  }
}
```

Here, invoking the vercel-build command would trigger the generate command to update the PrismaClient with newly added model. You can remove the migrate deploy command if you are not using Prisma Migrate.

Comment: That's interesting. I see `vercel-build` mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70745163/470749 which links to https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/deployment/deployment-guides/deploying-to-vercel#vercel-build-hook Thanks.